# Несколько вопросов по XMLPullParser

Tags: android, xml, xmlparser

Есть такой XML файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<quiz>
    <question
        title="Question ONE">
        <answer_one title="First answer">true</answer_one>
        <answer_two title="Second answer">false</answer_two>
        <answer_three title="Third answer">false</answer_three>
        <answer_four title="Fourth answer">false</answer_four>
    </question>
    <question
        title="Question TWO">
        <answer_one title="First answer">false</answer_one>
        <answer_two title="Second answer">true</answer_two>
        <answer_three title="Third answer">false</answer_three>
        <answer_four title="Fourth answer">false</answer_four>
    </question>
    <question
        title="Question THREE">
        <answer_one title="First answer">false</answer_one>
        <answer_two title="Second answer">false</answer_two>
        <answer_three title="Third answer">false</answer_three>
        <answer_four title="Fourth answer">true</answer_four>
    </question>
    <question
        title="Question FOUR">
        <answer_one title="First answer">false</answer_one>
        <answer_two title="Second answer">true</answer_two>
        <answer_three title="Third answer">false</answer_three>
        <answer_four title="Fourth answer">false</answer_four>
    </question>
    <question
        title="Question FIVE">
        <answer_one title="First answer">false</answer_one>
        <answer_two title="Second answer">true</answer_two>
        <answer_three title="Third answer">false</answer_three>
        <answer_four title="Fourth answer">false</answer_four>
    </question>
</quiz>
```

Задача пропарсить его с помощью `XMLPullParser` и записать в `ArrayList` (для начала). Код `MainActivity`

```
package com.example.lexzcq.eyewsefs;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final static String TAG = "log";
    private ArrayList<TrueFalse> mQuestionBank = new ArrayList<> ();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
        getQuestionsFromXML ();
        for (int i = 0; i < mQuestionBank.size (); i++) {
            Log.i (TAG, "Question: " + mQuestionBank.get (i).getQuestion () + "\n");
            Log.i (TAG, "TEXT Answer ONE: " + mQuestionBank.get (i).getFirstAnswer ().getAnswerText () + "\n");
            Log.i (TAG, "STATE Anser One:" + mQuestionBank.get (i).getFirstAnswer ().getState () + "\n");

            Log.i (TAG, "TEXT Answer TWO: " + mQuestionBank.get (i).getSecondAnswer ().getAnswerText () + "\n");
            Log.i (TAG, "STATE Anser TWO:" + mQuestionBank.get (i).getSecondAnswer ().getState () + "\n");

            Log.i (TAG, "TEXT Answer THREE: " + mQuestionBank.get (i).getThirdAnswer ().getAnswerText () + "\n");
            Log.i (TAG, "STATE Anser THREE:" + mQuestionBank.get (i).getThirdAnswer ().getState () + "\n");

            Log.i (TAG, "TEXT Answer FOUR: " + mQuestionBank.get (i).getFourthAnswer ().getAnswerText () + "\n");
            Log.i (TAG, "STATE Anser FOUR:" + mQuestionBank.get (i).getFourthAnswer ().getState () + "\n");

        }
    }

    private void getQuestionsFromXML () {
        XmlPullParser parser = getResources ().getXml (R.xml.questions);

        String question = "";
        TrueFalse item;
        String title = "";
        boolean state;

        Answer answerOne = null;
        Answer answerTwo = null;
        Answer answerThree = null;
        Answer answerFour = null;
        try {
            while (parser.getEventType () != parser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (parser.getEventType () == parser.START_TAG && parser.getName ().equals ("question")) {
                    question = parser.getAttributeValue (null, "title");

                   while (parser.getEventType () != parser.END_TAG) {
                        title = parser.getAttributeValue (null, "title").toString ();

                        if (parser.getEventType () == parser.START_TAG && parser.getName ().equals ("answer_one")) {

                            if (parser.getText ().toString ().equals ("true")) {
                                state = true;
                            } else {
                                state = false;
                            }
                            answerOne = new Answer (title, state);
                        }

                        if (parser.getEventType () == parser.START_TAG && parser.getName ().equals ("answer_two")) {
                            title = parser.getAttributeValue (null, "title").toString ();
                            if (parser.getText ().equalsIgnoreCase ("true")) {
                                state = true;
                            } else {
                                state = false;
                            }
                            answerTwo = new Answer (title, state);
                        }

                        if (parser.getEventType () == parser.START_TAG && parser.getName ().equals ("answer_three")) {
                            title = parser.getAttributeValue (null, "title").toString ();
                            if (parser.getText ().equalsIgnoreCase ("true")) {
                                state = true;
                            } else {
                                state = false;
                            }
                            answerThree = new Answer (title, state);
                        }

                        if (parser.getEventType () == parser.START_TAG && parser.getName ().equals ("answer_four")) {
                            title = parser.getAttributeValue (null, "title").toString ();
                            if (parser.getText ().equalsIgnoreCase ("true")) {
                                state = true;
                            } else {
                                state = false;
                            }
                            answerFour = new Answer (title, state);
                        }

                        parser.next ();
                    }


                    item = new TrueFalse (question, answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour);
                    mQuestionBank.add (item);

                }
                parser.next ();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно, как пройтись по всем тегам что бы занести их значения в `ArrayList`? У меня банально ничего не выводит в лог.
P.S. У меня ещё есть 2 класса: `TrueFalse` - класс с вопросом, вариантами ответа и правильностью каждого ответа и `Answer` - с заголовком вопроса и правильностью/неправильностью.

Comment: Почему не использовать другой парсер?

Comment: например какой?

Comment: например dom ....

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но не получилось нормально распарсить с помощью дома.

Comment: @Arthur Пожалуйста, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

#### РЕШЕНИЕ

Переделать XML по следующей схеме

```
<quiz>
    <question
        title="Вопрос"
        answer_one_name="Первый ответ"
        answer_one_state="true"

        answer_two_name="Второй ответ"
        answer_two_state="false"

        answer_three_name="Третий ответ"
        answer_three_state="false"

        answer_four_name="Четвёртый ответ"
        answer_four_state="false"/>
</quiz>
```

Код метода, который парсит XML

```
private void getQuestionsFromXML () {
        XmlPullParser parser = getResources ().getXml (R.xml.questions);
        
        String question;
        TrueFalse item;
        Answer answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour;
        try {
            while (parser.getEventType () != parser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (parser.getEventType () == parser.START_TAG && parser.getName ().equals ("question")) {

                    question = parser.getAttributeValue (null, "title");
//каждый экземпляр класса Answer принимает на вход String (вариант ответа) и boolean (истинность ответа).
//каждый экземпляр класса TrueFalse принимает String (вопрос) и 4 экземпляра Answer
answerOne = new Answer (parser.getAttributeValue (null, "answer_one_name"),
                            Boolean.valueOf (parser.getAttributeValue (null, "answer_one_state")));

                    answerTwo = new Answer (parser.getAttributeValue (null, "answer_two_name"),
                            Boolean.valueOf (parser.getAttributeValue (null, "answer_two_state")));

                    answerThree = new Answer (parser.getAttributeValue (null, "answer_three_name"),
                            Boolean.valueOf (parser.getAttributeValue (null, "answer_three_state")));

                    answerFour = new Answer (parser.getAttributeValue (null, "answer_four_name"),
                            Boolean.valueOf (parser.getAttributeValue (null, "answer_four_state")));

                    item = new TrueFalse (question, answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour);
                    mQuestionBank.add (item);
                }
                parser.next ();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
```

На сколько я понял XMLPullParser не умеет работать с вложенными (nested) тегами, либо же я не понял как его заставить работать с ними.